# How to get POST and GET data from a FORM in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, forms

I need to get an understanding about how you can handle get and post data in a form in asp.net in these 2 situations:

```
You submit a form with GET method: 
action: "form.php" 
parameters: text1=test

You submit a form with POST method: 
action: "form.php?text1=sometext" 
parameters: text1=somedifferenttext
```

I know these 3 commands:

```
String val1 = Page.Request["text1"];
String val2 = Page.Request.Form["text1"];
String val3 = Page.Request.QueryString["text1"];
```

I wonder what are the exact commands to access get and post variables directly?

Comment: your actions are backwards above.  GET uses ? format in the URL.

Comment: @Lou Franco - so does POST. Both GET and POST have QS, POST also has a request body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get variables are stored in the [query string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(VS.90).aspx):

```
String getText1 = Page.Request.QueryString["text1"];
```

Post variables are stored in the [form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(VS.90).aspx):

```
String postText1 = Page.Request.Form["text1"];
```

If you want to know more about the difference between Get and Post variables, I'd suggest having a read of this question: [When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

Answer (score 0):

For a GET, `Page.Request.RawUrl` will get you the original querystring.  You need to parse the whole URL to get it.

If it's a POST, read it from `Page.Request.InputStream`

Answer (score 0):

It might also be useful to know that both `Page.Request.Form` and `Page.Request.QueryString` are `NameValueCollection` objects. So if you want to iterate over their keys, you can use `Page.Request.Form.Keys` and `Page.Request.QueryString.Keys`.